# Javascript object defaulting

Tags: javascript

I want a code-golf solution for something that does the equivalent of the following:

```
myFunc = function( config ){
    if ( typeof config !== 'object' ) { config = {}; }

    config.property = config.property || 123;
};
```

Basically, is there a shorter way to ensure I am always passing an object, create it if not, and assign random values to it?

Comment: Can `config` be anything? Semantically, it looks like it will either be undefined or an object (since you're assigning properties it must be in fact). Is there a reason why you don't use `||`?

Comment: be carefull, typeof null == "object" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a merge helper, usually `jQuery.Extend()` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)). But if you didn't want to use jQuery, a similar helper would be trivial to write. But I would normally do something like:

```
myFunc = function( config ){
    var defaults = { property: 123 };
    config = $.extend({}, defaults, config);
};
```

Basically, you are extending an empty object with the defaults, then the config you pass in. You will always get a new object that has at least your `defaults` properties. I would definately recommend abstracting your object merging code into its own helper, if only so you don't repeat the same logic in every constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative that is a little more efficient in defaulting the values.  In the current code (with the `||` short-circuiting on the right-side of the assignment), assignments are *always* made, even if a value is already set.  Using the syntax below, assignments are only made when the default value is needed.

```
var myFunc = function(config) {
    config || (config = {});
    config.property || (config.property = 123);
};
```

Please note that this is a micro-optimization and will never make a measurable performance difference, but I think it's a neat approach and the question itself is kind of micro-optimizey to start with :)

---

Edit: this is probably assumed, but perhaps worth saying anyway.  Just make sure that your "is checked?" expression on the left-hand side of the `||` makes sense for the type of values being set.  E.g., if `0` is a valid value, then you would want a more robust expression than what's currently there (which will assign the default on any falsey value).  An alternative would be to check if the property is defined.

Answer (score 0):

One liner, although variable names are kept longer for readability:

```
myFunc = function(config) {
 (config.property) ? config : {property: 123};
}
```

Comment: For the record, it would throw an error in case config is undefined.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything, except for throw an error when config is undefined (as pimvdb pointed out).  No assignments are ever made.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to protect against config being passed as something other than a normal object, I don't think you can shorten it or use most of the other versions offered here.  In fact, I think you have to add the extra test to see if config is not `null` because `null` has typeof 'object'.

```
myFunc = function( config ){
    if ( !config || typeof config !== 'object' ) { config = {}; }

    config.property = config.property || 123;
};
```

Test cases that this works for:

```
myFunc(null);
myFunc();
myFunc("{}");
myFunc("{property: 100}");
myFunc("aa");
myFunc([]);
myFunc(5);
```